# Examining variables while debugging in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm looking for a way to examine the value of variables while debugging in Android Studio. In Xcode, you can type commands into the terminal window to execute code. For example: `po user.name` would print the user's name. There is a similar facility in the Chrome debugger. You could just type `user.getFriends()` and it would output the list of friends.

Does something like this exist in Android Studio? At the moment I'm limited to having to examine the variables in the `Variables` window which is slower and much less flexible because you can't print the value of functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When debugging an application, you can set a breakpoint and when that triggers, you can right click in the editor and select 'Evaluate Expression...'  I believe this will give you close to what you are looking for.